# Why apply is so important for lisp evaluator?

Tags: lisp, sicp

I have read chapter 4 of SICP, and just found that the first section lists the most important functions for implementing a evaluator, `eval` and `apply`, I understand that `eval` is very important, but why `apply` is so important?  For some language, there is totally no `apply` such as in Javascript.

Edit: Sorry about that I am wrong about there is no apply in Javascript, please just ignore that.

Comment: I am sure there are some equivalent in JavaScript  :)

Comment: JavaScript *does* have an `apply`, doesn't it? I'm not a JS expert, but what's https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eval/apply thing in SICP (and elsewhere) is separating two major parts of an evaluator.  The first part, the one that `eval` is doing, is dealing with the syntactic translation of code to its meaning -- but it's doing almost nothing except dispatching over the expression type.  As you can see in the book, there are various `eval-foo`s for various "special forms", since each of them has its own unique evaluation rule.

Now, the most important form that the evaluator needs to deal with is function application.  In fact, it's so important that there is no keyword for this form (otherwise, you'd see `apply` or whatever littering scheme/lisp code).  Instead, if a form begins with something that is not a known special form (and in real implementations, not a known macro) then the evaluator takes it to be a function application.  At this point, to evaluate a function call, you need to evaluate the function itself (the first form) and all of its arguments, and then you need to *apply* the first value over the rest.  A major enlightenment moment here is to realize that there is a major difference between this `eval` and `apply` -- the former inherently deals with *syntax*, but the latter deals with *values*.

As a side note, several people confused this with the built-in `apply` function that Scheme and Lisp implementation have.  Why that function needs to be in the language is completely unrelated to the SICP point (roughly, it provides functionality that you cannot implement without it, it is a form of reflection from the implementation into the language).  I don't even think that the SICP evaluators even make `apply` available in the interpreted language.  If you're looking for more enlightenment, doing that (taking a SICP meta circular evaluator, and adding `apply` to the *interpreted* language) will be a nice exercise in reflection.

Answer (score 2):

It's how you run a function on an expression, aka 'apply' the function to the expression.

Note the code here:

<s>http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/code/ch4-mceval.scm</s> (dead link)

Answer (score 1):

Apply evaluates a function call. It takes a function and a list of arguments: `(apply fn args)`. If you have a language that supports function calls, you're probably going to have an apply function in your interpreter. The difference between Scheme and Javascript is that Scheme exposes this function not only to the interpreter, but also to the program that is *being* interpreted.

Comment: In this context, "evaluate" has a specific meaning, so this explanation isn't helping much.  More than that, you're talking about the `apply` function, and how that is related to the application that the book is talking about is a more subtle issue.

Comment: It is a subtle issue, but it seems to me that the OP is asking about exactly that issue because he mentions that JS doesn't have an apply function. The eval function performs case analysis on the type of expressions, and then each case decides how to evaluate that type of expression. The evaluator in SICP just happens to factor the code for evaluating a function call into a different function called apply. This isn't an essential feature of an evaluator: you could just as well have inlined the apply function into eval, although that may make the code less clear.

Comment: The distinction between the apply function inside the interpreter and the apply function isn't actually big. The apply function can be exposed directly to user programs by putting it into your primitive-procedure list.

Comment: Yes, see my reply.  Re the OPs confusion about `apply` I agree that it looks like the same kind of confusion, but going with it rather than explaining it won't help much...

Answer (score 0):

It isn't universal. For instance, it assumes strict semantics, whereas languages can be lazily evaluated.

However, the Lisp-based representation of the concept eliminates most issues of syntax, so that there are few distractions away from the bare semantics.

In order to talk about how some program is structured and interpreted, we need to refer to its syntax. If there is a distinct outer syntax which is visible, and an invisible inner syntax, the description becomes muddled. Lisp makes them almost one and the same. Plus, the processing itself is expressible in the same Lisp. We can easily talk about the interpretation of the syntax, since it is laid bare, and we have names for all the parts. Moreover, we can write the processing *in* that same syntax.