# Eval and Apply in SICP

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

What is so special about the SICP eval-apply loop? What is so enlightening about it?

I understand the process of evaluation, but do not understand what is so universal in it. Programmers also say that it represents the core of every programming language.

Comment: [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269132/16981884)